# Java String Replace Xml tag which has some specific word

Tags: java, xml, regex, string, replace

I need to remove XML tag in a string which ends with "section". For example in the below XML string

```
<OldSection>
    <sectionTitle>Sample Title</sectionTitle>
    <label> Hello Label </label>
    <heading>Hi </heading>
    <NewSection>
        <section>
            <InteractionSection>
                <sectionTitle>Section Title</sectionTitle>
                <label> Hello </label>
                <heading>Hi </heading>
                <para>
                    ...
                    ...
                </para>
            </InteractionSection>
        <section>
    </NewSection>
</OldSection>
```

I want to remove tags which ends with section i.e `<OldSection>, </OldSection>
,<NewSection></NewSection>,  <InteractionSection>, </InteractionSection>` etc. The tag alone should be removed and not the contents with in the tag.

I tried the following code but not working..

```
stringformat sf = new stringformat();

// REturns the xml string given as input 
String s = sf.getString(); 
String f = s; 

f = f.replaceAll("\\<*Section[^>].*?\\>", "");
```

Please any suggestions.

Comment: Use SAX.  Don't try to use regular expressions to crunch XML.

Comment: Yuo can use also XPAth library, run xml and look for nodes that you want to delete.maybe can i pass you and example, let me look for.

Comment: try this `\\<.*Section>`

Comment: In question like this you should inculde what exactly is not working.  Otherwise people have to guess what your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to play with Strings using regex. I would suggest that you do marshalling and unmarshalling. Unmarshall your XML into a class. Copy your requisite class contents into another class using Apache Commons' BeanUtils and then marshall this back into XML.